# Xml Reading with backward Compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, backwards-compatibility

The XML that i am currently working is directly formed using XML serializer (Serializing Class and its nested counter parts)

Also if there is an addition of a new `Property` is directly handled by the serializer but the problem comes when there is a `deletion of property (value Type)` or `removal of and entire class or addition of class`

I wish to read the old as well as the new XML files.... I cant seem to figure out how..

## Process

[image: Expected XML upgrade process]

## Some ways

But i don't think these are good for a maintainable code

1) Make the custom XML parser (this will be less flexible as every time the change is done the  parser has to be updated and hence tested again).
2) Use multiple Models then migrate from old to new (Taking essential components)
3) Export Old file and import the new file (This will also require another XML file and may b related to point 2)
4) Any other means (Please suggest)

I am not well versed with XML and its versioning.
Also is XML a good choice for this or Any other file type/DB that i can use in place of XML

Any help in this regard would be helpful.

Comment: There is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7hdy1ss.aspx), which uses [XMLDeserializationEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmldeserializationevents.aspx), (handles for unknowns)

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow your solution "#2" where I namespace version my models (Myapp.Models.V1.MyModel), this way you can maintain backward compatibility with clients still using the older schema (or in your case, loading an older file).

As suggested in the comments, you can use a simple attribute on the root node to determine the version, and use either xmlreader, or even a simple regex on the first line of the file to read the version number.

As far as your second question, about file type/db, depending on your needs, I would highly recommend looking at a document database like MongoDB or RavenDB, as implementation is straightforward/simple, and does not require the use of an ORM tool like entity framework to handle proper separation of concerns. If you need something portable, in the cases such as desktop app "save file", SqlLite is a good file based databases, but you will likely want to use an ORM for mapping your model to your database.

Links:

- MongoDB: http://www.mongodb.org/
- RavenDB: http://ravendb.net/
- Sqllite: http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) . I Like the Idea for loading different Model for the XML but how will I distinguish without reading if the file is of V1,V2 or V1.5 ...

Comment: @AnkeshDave I store the version in an attribute. It's really easy to read the root element + attribute (and it can written very efficiently using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx)).

Comment: @AnkeshDave you can use something like `XmlReader` or a DOM (`XmlDocument` / `XDocument`) to parse the first few nodes so you can check the revision number; you can also just have a really simple base model that **only** knows about the revision attribute: deserialize as that to get the revision number, then deserialize *again* when you know which version to use

Answer (score 0):

In most ways, `XmlSerializer` already has pretty good version support built in. In most cases, if you add or remove elements it isn't a problem: extra (unexpected) data will be silently ignored - or put into the `[XmlAnyElement]` / `[XmlAnyAttribute]` member (if one) for round-trip. Any missing data just won't be initialized. The only noticeable problem is with sub-types, but adding and removing sub-types (or entire types) is going to be fairly fundamental to *any* serializer. One common option in the case of sub-types is: use a single model, but just don't remove any sub-types (adding sub-types is fine, assuming you don't need to be forwards compatible). However if this is not possible, the multiple models (model per revision) is not a bad approach.

Comment: I use model per *breaking* revision and have a top-level "version" attribute. As pointed out, XmlSerializer is very flexible and can handle many minor revisions just fine. (I also require that A->C upgrades go through B: A->B->C.)